# Mongoose text search - deep nested indexing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongo DB's [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) feature, we can create searchable indexes which I'm doing in Mongoose by applying via. the Schema, e.g:

```
RandomSchema.index({ description: 'text', notice: 'text'});
```

where an object resembles

```
{
  description: "first",
  notice: "next"
  .. 
}
```

This works fine - but how can I get this to work for nested text values?

Neither of the following work:

```
RandomSchema.index({ "randObj.title": 'text'});
RandomSchema.index({ randObj: { title: 'text' }});
```

where an example could be

```
{ 
  randObj: {
    title: "random string"
    ..
  }
  .. 
}
```

*Also,* if a document is using populated fields, are we able to index those string fields as well?